# Jquery Data tables Date formatting after ASP.NET Serializer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, date, datatables

Ive got a SQL database query being serialized by ASP and then the JSON being sent to Javascript to display Datatables. As you are probably aware dates are not formatted correctly and instead of the date i see: `/Date(1424563200000)/`.

Ive trying to fix this by using:

`function ToJavaScriptDate(value) {
    var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
    var results = pattern.exec(value);
    var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
    return (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
}`

But how can I call this function each time my Datatable trys to read a date?

My table configuration looks like this:

```
    $('#YourTaskTable').dataTable({
    "ajax": "App_JSON/YourTaskTable.txt",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "TName" },
        { "data": "RegistrationNo" },
        { "data":  "DueDate"}
    ]
});
```

and ive tired doing this:

```
    $('#YourTaskTable').dataTable({
    "ajax": "App_JSON/YourTaskTable.txt",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "TName" },
        { "data": "RegistrationNo" },
        { "data": ToJavaScriptDate("DueDate")} //Function call added here  
    ]
});
```

But this does not work and i dont see any date, How do I call this function here to convert the date?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

Use [mRender](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns#mRender) for this.  Note you'll have to use `aoColumns` instead of `columns`, and you get your data from `full[]` which is the datasource for the row.

```
"aoColumns": [
{
    'mRender': function(data, type, full) {
       return ToJavaScriptDate(full[2])
    }
},
etc...
```